# pgfplots legend: how can I set the column/row order of legend entries?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

By default, pgfplots seems to add legend entries row-wise.  However, I've plot where I'd like a two-column legend (16 curves) and the first 8 entries to be added to the first column before starting the second column.  Gnuplot has this behaviour by default, but I can't control the legend style as well as in pgfplots.  My code is shown below.  Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    legend style={%
        at={(.99,0.99)},
        anchor=north east,
        legend columns=2,
        font=\footnotesize,
    },
    width=16.18cm,height=6.18cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=100.01,
    ymin=0,ymax=8,
    xtick={0,10,...,100},
    ytick={0,2,...,8},
    xlabel={\large Downstream distance, $x$/[cm]},
    ylabel={\large Height profile, $h(x,t)$/[cm]},
    grid=major,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
\addplot gnuplot [id=p1] {07-09-14/t_0.25.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p2] {07-09-14/t_0.5.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p3] {07-09-14/t_0.75.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p4] {07-09-14/t_1.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p5] {07-09-14/t_1.25.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p6] {07-09-14/t_1.5.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p7] {07-09-14/t_1.75.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p8] {07-09-14/t_2.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p9] {07-09-14/t_2.25.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p10] {07-09-14/t_2.5.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p11] {07-09-14/t_2.75.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p12] {07-09-14/t_3.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p13] {07-09-14/t_3.25.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p14] {07-09-14/t_3.5.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p15] {07-09-14/t_3.75.dat u 1:2};
\addplot gnuplot [id=p16] {07-09-14/t_4.dat u 1:2};

\legend{{$t=0.25$ s},{$t=0.5$ s},{$t=0.75$ s},{$t=1$ s},{$t=1.25$ s},{$t=1.5$ s},{$t=1.75$ s},{$t=2$ s},{$t=2.25$ s},{$t=2.5$ s},{$t=2.75$ s},{$t=3$ s},{$t=3.25$ s},{$t=3.5$ s},{$t=3.75$ s},{$t=4$ s}};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get precisely what you described from your example. Two columns eight rows.

Comment: there is some `transposed legend` option (or something like that) which might fit your needs

Comment: +1 for Christian. The exact option name is transpose legend. (page 123 of manual)

Comment: While the question does not have a MWE, it has an example, and according to the votes on Christian Feuersaengers comment, I am not the only one who came here looking for this. (Sometimes google is just faster than going through the manual)

Comment: I came here looking for exactly the same problem, and the option suggested by @ChristianFeuersänger helped me as well. So my suggestion is to reopen this question, as several people seem to have similar issues.

Comment: I also had this problem, and was helped by the existance of this question.